# Saving changes in docker project

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I just started a django project with docker, I used the [cookiecutter-django template](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) that is discussed in the book Two scoops of django.

I am trying to set it all up in OSX, but I am having some trouble with the [following part](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/developing-locally-docker.html#prerequisites) from the documentation:

> Saving changes
>
> If you are using OS X or Windows, you need to create a
> /data partition inside the virtual machine that runs the docker deamon
> in order make all changes persistent. If you don’t do that your /data
> directory will get wiped out on every reboot. To create a persistent
> folder, log into the virtual machine by running:
>
> $ docker-machine ssh dev1
>
> $ sudo su
>
> $ echo 'ln -sfn /mnt/sda1/data /data' >>
> /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh

However, if I execute these commands, and try to start my docker project, I get the following error:

ERROR: Cannot start container 182a38022fbdf65f7a64f1ca5475a3414084d11c91f1cb48bffc6f76491baf4a: mkdir /data: file exists

I'm quite stuck at this point, do you guys have an idea what I could do to get this up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end this was fixed by making the directory in the local machine. I did that with the following code when adding the line to the bootlocal.sh file:

> $ mkdir /mnt/sda1/data